# What JUnit command i should use to check that, the expected is not equal to the actual.

Tags: java, junit, assert

So the question is: what JUnit command i should use to check that the expected is not equal to the actual. For example i use assertEquals like this

```
assertEquals(tr1.detectTriangle(), tr1.TR_EQUILATERAL);
```

So here expected variable is 2 but actual is 1 and test fails. What command i should use to make this test passed?

Comment: assertNotEquals or assertFalse should do it.  If the method throws an exception you should add expected value to the @Test annotation.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096650/why-doesnt-junit-provide-assertnotequals-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, there is the simple `assertNotEquals()`, but I typically suggest to use the one and only assert you really need: `assertThat`!

```
assertThat(actual, is(expected));
```

or, in your case:

```
assertThat(actual, not(expected));
```

Where `is()` and `not()` are [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matchers that do exactly what their names imply.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me!

Comment: @NikitaKozlovsky then please  mark it as "correct answer" and also concider an upvote.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle He cant upvote ... just 1 rep, the poor soul. But I am fine with an accept ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat, thank you for pointing this out.  I've been so engrained in my old assert habits that I've never used it.  Shame on me!

Comment: @GhostCat, please, fix a misprint "expecred" -> "expected". I tried to fix, but at least 6 changed chars are accepted by stackoverflow :)